# In Axis2/Rampart, how can I get SAML Assertion in PasswordCallBackHandler

Tags: apache-axis, rampart

I am securing my SOAP based Web Services using STS. The tokens are SAML 1.0 tokens. The SAML tokens are added in SOAP Header as security header. I need the SAMLAssertions as I need to get the nameIdentifier from the SAMLAssertion.

Can I get hold of the SAMLAssertion in PasswordCallBackHandler class. Is there any other way of doing it.

Comment: Since no answers have been posted, I am adding my investigation result so far. It seems what I want to do is not possible in a PasswordCallBack. Was going through the RampartConfig.java class. This is not provided. Will post my strategy , in case somebody needs it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to identity a way to do what I wanted. I will list down the solution point wise :

- Its not possible via Password CallBackHandler as axis does not give access to the MessageContext.
- Solution is to create a Custom Handler class which extends org.apache.axis2.handlers.AbstractHandler . Since in my case its a SAML2 Security Token, I wanted my handler to be called 'post-security' phase in 'InFlow' phaseorder. This ensures that the security header has passed the security phase.  The handler class has a invoke method which has a MessageContext as its parameter. MessageContext gives you access to the whole SOAPEnvelope and its content. Following is the skeleton code you can build on :

  ```
    public class LIMSConHandler extends AbstractHandler  {
        private Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(LIMSConHandler.class);

        public InvocationResponse invoke(MessageContext ctx) throws  AxisFault {

        //following code gives you access to the soapEnvelope
        SOAPEnvelope msgEnvelope = ctx.getEnvelope();
        SOAPHeader msgHeader = msgEnvelope.getHeader();
        //add your logic to extract the security header and SAML assertion

        return InvocationResponse.CONTINUE;
   }
  ```

Bind this handler to the 'Post-Security' custom phase in axis2.xml

```
    <phaseOrder type="InFlow">
     .........
    <phase name="Security"/>
    <phase name="PostSecurity">
    <handler name="LIMSConHandler"    class="labware.web.ws.control.LIMSConHandler"/>
```

I welcome input on this.